# The Image file could not be opened Azure Blob Storage

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, azure-blob-storage, django-storage

Hi I have written a scraper that uploads images directly to Azure Blob Storage

The upload is successful however upon opening the file it gives an error 'The Image file could not be opened'
When saving locally it works fine, so somewhere when converting to Bytes to upload to the blob it breaks. Please help

I have tried converting it to a string as per the commented out code however that did not work either - Many thanks in advance

````
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME, account_key=AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY, connection_string=AZURE_CONNECTION_STRING)

r = requests.get(image_url, stream=True)
image_name='test_thumb.jpg'
output = io.BytesIO()
r.raw.decode_content = True
with Image.open(r.raw) as image:
    image.thumbnail((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image.save(image_name, format="JPEG")
#     thumbnail_as_string = base64.b64encode(output.getvalue())
    block_blob_service.create_blob_from_bytes(container_name="media", blob_name=image_name, blob=image.tobytes())```
````

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

```
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME, account_key=AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY, connection_string=AZURE_CONNECTION_STRING)
def create_thumbnail(image_url, image_name):
    r = requests.get(image_url, stream=True)
    image_stream = io.BytesIO()
    r.raw.decode_content = True
    with Image.open(r.raw) as image:
        image.thumbnail((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        image.save(image_stream, format="JPEG")
        image_stream.seek(0)
        block_blob_service.create_blob_from_bytes(container_name="media", blob_name=image_name, blob=image_stream.read())
```